# failed to send array in url in workligh application using jquerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am building a hybrid application in IBM worklight using jquerymobile.
I want to send the json array returned by server php to another page in the url. The codes are shown below:
**searchPools.js file**
(file from which the another page is called)

```
$(document).undelegate('#srhPool', 'click').delegate('#srhPool', 'click', function() {
                    var source = $("#csource1").val();
                    var destination = $("#cdest1").val();
                    var poolDate = $("#pooldate1").val();

                    if(source == null || source == "")
                        $("#csource1").parent().css('border','2px solid red');
                    if(destination == null || destination == "")
                        $("#cdest1").parent().css('border','2px solid red');
                    if(poolDate == null || poolDate == "")
                        $("#pooldate1").parent().css('border','2px solid red');


                    if(source == null || source == "" || destination == null || destination == "" || poolDate == null || poolDate == "" || validateRadio == false){
                        alert("Oops! Your Pooling Info is Incomplete.");
                    }
                    else{
                        savePool(userId, source, destination, poolDate, preferVehicle);
                    }
                });

            //save pool info

               function savePool(userId, source, destination, poolDate, preferVehicle){
                   $.mobile.utils.showWaitBox("a", "Wait! Searching Poolers...");
                    var invocationData9 = {
                            adapter : 'registerUser',
                            procedure : 'searchPoolData',
                            parameters : [userId, source, destination, poolDate, preferVehicle]
                    };

                    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData9, {
                        onSuccess : poolSuccess,
                        onFailure : poolFailure,
                    });
                }

                function poolSuccess(result){
                    $.mobile.utils.hideWaitBox();
                    var invocationResult = result.invocationResult;
                    var array1 = invocationResult.pools;
                    var dataurl2 = '?array='+array1;

                    $.mobile.changePage('../../pages/passenger/poolResults.html'+dataurl2, {transition: "slide"});

                }

                function poolFailure(result){
                    $.mobile.utils.hideWaitBox();
                    WL.Logger.error('Search Unsuccessful');
                }
```

**poolResults.js**(the file where the array is accessed)

```
$(document).on( 'pagebeforeshow', '#poolResults', function(event){

    var params = new Array();

     function getParams(){
             var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');

             if (idx != -1) {
             var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1, document.URL.length).split('&');
             for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
             nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
             params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
             }
             }
             return params;
         }
         params = getParams();
         getArray = unescape(params["array"]);
         alert(getArray);
});
```

Its not working.
 What I want to do is that I clicked a button in a page, then some results are retreived through http adapters. In the searchPools.js file, the values are successfully obtained in the poolSuccess function. Now, these values are to be displayed on the other page which is showed using $.mobile.changePage.
 I want to know the way I am using is right, or some other way is available for achieving this.

Comment: What is not working here ? worklight adatper or your js code?

Comment: worklight adapter is working successfully. What I mentioned is that the array send in the url is not accessed in the other js file. Also, tell me that can we send json array in the url as I did.

Comment: You are getting it as a json so why cant you just call a function in changepage successhandler and send json as a parameter and do your work with the json there?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say, please explain a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the array like this

```
$.mobile.changePage('page2.html', { dataUrl : "page2.html?parameter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : true, changeHash : true });
```

and retrive them like

```
$("#index").live('pagebeforeshow', function (event, data) {
    var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
    parameter = parameters.replace("parameter=","");  
    alert(parameter);    
});
```

[For More Info See The Link](http://www.gajotres.net/passing-data-between-jquery-mobile-pages/)

For your understanding Pass it as

```
$.mobile.changePage("newPage.html", {data:{ param1 : YOUR JSON } });
```

And retrive it as

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#newPageId").on("pageshow", onPageShow);

        function onPageShow(e,data)
        {
            var url = $.url(document.location);

            var param1 = url.param("param1");
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I understand that but as I mentioned I want to send the whole json result which I get. As fas as I understood that you want to say that I send just a paramter (for example, id) to other page and then call http adapters from there and retrieve results.

Comment: Yes instead of `data: { 'paremeter' : '123' }` you can send your json data see the link for reference.

Comment: OK! But my application structure is- I have a button on one page, when I clicked it, then http adapter is called as you can see in the searchPools.js code. Now on poolSuccess function I get the json array results. Now I want to display these array results on the other page changed using $.mobile.changePage. So, how I do this. What I tried is that send the array in the url to next page, can it work?

Comment: @himanshu.miet.cse you have tried the **chagepage jquery syntax wrongly** try it by the way which i have show you above.

Comment: I used the same syntax for sending values, and it works. But I don't know array can be send by using this technique. If I used $.mobile.changePage("newPage.html", {data:{ param1 : YOUR JSON } }); as you mentioned can I send whole array using this technique.

Comment: @himanshu.miet.cse try to send the complete `result` and iterate it in your new page.